Obtain the inputs that satisfy constraints with Tensorflow for a trained model with Sklearn
Assume, we have a trained SVM model with good performance. There are two features and two classes. It is desired to obtain the input (or features) that satisfies conditions. For the point [11.0, 15.0], its predicted label from SVM is 0, however assume the desired class is 1. With minimal changes of [11.0, 15.0], we want to have a new feature where the label from the model would be 1.  For the following code, get error: Shape of tensor dummy_input [] is not compatible with expected shape [2]. [Op:EnsureShape]
import tensorflow as tf 

desired_output  = tf.constant(1.0, dtype=tf.float32)
initial_features = tf.Variable([np.mean(X_train, axis=0)], dtype=tf.float32)


# Optimization settings
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01)

def sklearn_predict(input_var):
    x_np = input_var.numpy()  # Convert to numpy for sklearn
    return svm_classifier.predict_proba(x_np)[0][1]

# Wrap the sklearn predict function with tf.py_function
# @tf.function
def differentiable_predict(input_var):
    result = tf.py_function(sklearn_predict, [input_var], tf.float32)
    result = tf.ensure_shape(result, [X_train.shape[1]])
    return result


def loss_fn(input_var):
    prediction = differentiable_predict(input_var)
    return tf.square(prediction - desired_output) + tf.norm([[11.0, 15.0]]) - input_var, axis=1, ord='euclidean')**2


for step in range(500):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
          loss = loss_fn(initial_features)

    grads = tape.gradient(loss, [initial_features])
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, [initial_features]))


    # Break if loss is small enough
    if loss < 1e-3:
        break

print("Optimal feature values:", initial_features)
print("Predicted output with optimal features:", svm_classifier.predict(initial_features.numpy()))

